# text file read from remote systems

Tags: scripting, vbscript

Hi Scripting Experts....

Looking for your help on below code....RemoteServersList.Txt and i wanted to call every system like \RemoteServerName\E$\V2\log.Txt I am missing few lines of code ...

kindly help me ....
Thanks lot....

```
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set InFile = fso.OpenTextFile("RemoteServersList.Txt")

Const ForReading = 1

Do While Not (InFile.atEndOfStream)

strComputer = InFile.ReadLine


today = Date()

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


strFilePath = "\\" & strComputer & "\E$\V2\" ' This is wrong 'here I am missing a 'code.. looking for your help

Set InputFile = fso.OpenTextFile("strFilePath\log.txt", 1)  ' This is wrong here I am 'missing a code.. looking for your help


Set out = fso.OpenTextFile("error.log", 2)

    Do Until InputFile.AtEndOfStream
      line = InputFile.ReadLine
      If Left(line, Len(today)+1) = "[" & today Then

    WScript.Echo "Hello" ' I need to append this to output file
    out.WriteLine line & vbTab & InputFile.ReadLine & vbTab & strComputer


            If InStr(line, "error") > 0 Then
        ' line contains "error"
        out.WriteLine line & vbTab & InputFile.ReadLine & vbTab & strComputer

        End If
    End If


    Loop

InputFile.Close
out.Close


Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

RemoteServerList.txt is a txt file that contains a list of server, written as this:

```
server-1
server-2
server-3
etc.
```

and on each server you have to read this text file:

```
\\server-1\e$\V2\log.txt
\\server-2\e$\V2\log.txt
```

?

The first problem I see in your code is in the string assignment, this should be correct:

```
strFilePath = "\\" & strComputer & "\E$\V2\"
Set InputFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strFilePath & "log.txt", 1)
```

but where do you want to write the error.log file? localy or on the remote machine?

If you want it on the local machine, it's better if you open the file only once, at the beginning of your script, just below Set Inifile.

And you have to use *CreateTextFile* or open it with *fso.OpenTextFile("error.log", 2, True)* if the file does not already exist:

```
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set InFile = fso.OpenTextFile("RemoteServersList.Txt")
Set out = fso.CreateTextFile("error.log")

Const ForReading = 1

Do While Not (InFile.atEndOfStream)
  strComputer = InFile.ReadLine
  today = Date()
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  strFilePath = "\\" & strComputer & "\E$\V2\"

  Set InputFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strFilePath & "log.txt", 1)
  Do Until InputFile.AtEndOfStream

    If (condition) Then
      out.WriteLine [write something to output file]
    End If

  Loop
  InputFile.close

Loop

out.Close
InFile.Close
```